# Having issues passing values to my other page with post

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP, and have been trying to make this work but nothing.. basically i have a simple registration form

I would appreciate your help

Comment: Missed the bit on [not using `extract` on user-submitted data](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php#refsect1-function.extract-notes) did you? (_the etc. **includes** $_POST as well_) Also, raw INSERTs from the form. [Another no-no] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php).  **PS** I _believe_ it has to do with the top `<?xml...` line (and php seeing `?>` not split up). Remove that line and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should display PHP errors. Seems like PHP crashes on a half way, and we don't really know why. By the way U cant use the following array keys naming:
$_POST[fname]. It should be $_POST['fname']

Turn displaying errors on using this:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);

error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: where do i do this? sorry i am new to php

Comment: Just add the two lines of code to the beginning of your test.php.

Comment: it gave me this error Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

Comment: Your php don't use mysql extension. Find something that looks like this in your php.ini file -> ;extension=php_mysql.dll and remove ";". If this won't fix the problem you DO need to instal php with mysql extension, and turn extension on.

Comment: it is uncommented, also moved the php_mysql.dll to the C:/Windows/System32 and the libmysql.dll or something.. but nothing

Comment: Make sure U're fixing right ini file. Check it with phpinfo() inside your script. It will show which ini file is loaded. Also if mysql extension is enabled, you'll see a mysql block in the info list.

Answer (score 1):

Off-hand I'd guess 1 of two things (both relating to [display_errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) being disabled, so you're not getting any reason why it's failing):

1. Your print has an "unescaped" `?>` in it, so my guess is the compiler sees it and thinks it's done with PHP code. Often when this header is output from php, it is done so in this fashion:
   `<?php echo '<?xml ... ?'.'>'; ?>`
   Note the `.` concatenating the two characters to avoid compiler confusion.
2. Your print is missing a semicolon (`;`)

However, you also missed the bit on [not using `extract` on user-submitted data](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php#refsect1-function.extract-notes)

> **Do not use extract() on untrusted data**, like user input (i.e. $_GET, $_FILES, etc.).

(The etc. above would *include* `$_POST` as well) `extract()` is not necessary for `$_POST[]` to be populated, so do yourself a favor and just use `$_POST`.

Also, raw INSERTs from the form are [another no-no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php).

Comment: Ok, i understand but just for the sake of making it work for my own experience.. How do I turn on display_errors?

Comment: It gave me this error Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

Comment: @user710502: then your mysql extension isn't loaded. Make sure that `extension=php_mysql.dll` isn't commented out in your php.ini file.